# Allow to enter only 2 characters of same type in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to allow the user in a TextFormField to use only 2 spaces in the typed text.

If someone wants to type: `This is the text`, they will get `This is thetext`.

I have already created constraints:

```
  List<RegExp> _allowedRegexes(BuildContext context) {
    alphabet = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ;
    String allowedCharacters = '$alphabet ${alphabet.toLowerCase()}';
    List<RegExp> allowedRegexes = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < allowedCharacters.length; i++) {
      allowedRegexes.add(RegExp(allowedCharacters[i]));
    }
    return allowedRegexes;
  }

  TextInputFormatter _filterFormatter(BuildContext context) {
    return FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
      RegExp(_allowedRegexes(context).map((e) => e.pattern).join('|')),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the TextInputFormatter @Ghayoor Hussain mentioned, you can do something like this

```
class TwoSpacesFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    if (' '.allMatches(newValue.text).length > 2) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

And you use the input formatter as so

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    TwoSpacesFormatter(),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
        RegExp(_allowedRegexes(context).map((e) => e.pattern).join('|'))),
  ],
  // other properties...
)
```

Once there are two spaces, this makes it so that the user cannot type anymore spaces.